# How to integrate bootstrap css and js with my liferay 7.2 theme?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme, clay

I created a `liferay 7.2 theme` based on `gradle` with liferay developer Studio ( new Module project) , For now,I added some navigation menus and footer and contents , it looks not responsive anymore that's why I ask how to integrate bootstrap within my theme. 
Can I do so by importing the cdn bootstrap link inside the `portal_normal.ftl` ?
I heart about clay but I didn't understand how to proceed !

How can I fix this please?

thank you

Comment: Another case, where https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/364505 would be beneficial: Duplicate work: generated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Clay is an extension of Bootstrap’s open source CSS Framework](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/clay-css-and-themes)

By creating a Liferay theme, you have at your disposal clay. You should import it in your _custom.scss if it is not the case :

```
@import "clay/base";
```

Therefore, you can use all Bootstrap' css classes for responsive design.

[Here](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/importing-clay-css-into-a-theme) is a thread about importing clay into a Lifeay theme.